# How to append category and subcategory slug with product URLs in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento2

My current Product url is in this format : example.com/product_slug . I need to append the category and subcategory URLs along with this URL. The site is implemented using magento,which i am not much familiar with. Is there any option to do this via admin side ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked it but you need to set Category Id on Product Object. Try the code below:

```
$product->setCategoryId($categoryId)->getProductUrl();
```

I am quite sure that it will work for you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse magento's catalog url rewrite module.

You'll just have to pass the category and the store id as parameters.

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator $ProductUrlPathGenerator,
  ....

) {
  $this->ProductUrlPathGenerator = $ProductUrlPathGenerator;
  ....
}

public function fetchFullProductUrl($product)
{
  ...
  return $this->ProductUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPathWithSuffix($product, $storeId, $category);
}
```